# Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out - LINQ TO SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

I have a linq to sql inner join on multiple  tables. For some strange reason upon generation of the query my application breaks without any messages. I am designing an mvc application in code first.

Recently I have also been experiencing an unfamiliar error:

> **exception details**: system.componentmodel.win32exception: the wait operation timed out

Could someone assist me

Comment: Please share your code with the community. Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code, without it we can only guess what your issue is which can waste a lot of time for ourselves and yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround was to use lambda expressions and save to ViewBag e.g.

ViewBag.PassportNumber = (from x in db.Client where x.Id == Id select x.passportNumber).FirstOrDefault();